# MariaDB Error Reading Communication Packets

Tags: mysql, php, docker, mariadb

I have a problem. When I split my MariaDB from main server to another server (my database server is running MariaDB docker from latest tag) I got an error:

> Got an error writing communication packets

i have 2 server the one is a webserver (no db) the other is a ubuntu 20.04 with 4gig ram and 4 core(2gh per core)

The port is open and my PING is less than 1ms.

I tried with a basic WP site DB and the connection is OK, there was no problem, but my database is about 1GB and I guess this made this problem.

I also try to connect over private network (`192.168.100.25`) instead of public IP, but the problem is same.

Here is my MariaDB log

> Aborted connection 3 to db: 'wpdb' user: 'root' host: 'myip' (Got an error reading communication packets)

> Aborted connection 5 to db: 'wpdb' user: 'root' host: 'myip' (Got an error writing communication packets)

I also edited MariaDB config:

- increased max_allowed_packet to 1GB
- increased net_buffer_length to 1000000

but nothing changes!

here is mariadb variable :
https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/yHFRh7CnVC/

SHOW GLOBAL STATUS:
https://pastebin.pl/view/b3db2b91

show process list:

8,root,31.56.66.249:60612,,Query,0,starting,SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST,0

ulimit on server root:

```
ubuntu@rangoabzar:~$ ulimit -a 
ulimit -a 
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 15608
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 65536
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 1024
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 15608
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

ulimit in docker container:

```
root@63aa95764534:/#  ulimit -a
core file size          (blocks, -c) unlimited
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 15608
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 64
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 1048576
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) unlimited
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

[iostat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jmPxO.png)

[htop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A6Zoq.png)

Comment: Additional information request. 
RAM size, # cores, any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post on pastebin.com and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
E) STATUS;
AND Optional very helpful information, if available includes - 
htop OR top  for most active apps, 
ulimit -a       for a Linux/Unix list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device and core/cpu count, 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: @WilsonHauck hi i edited the question by the way  my mariadb server is just a ubuntu 20.04 with a docker running mariadb no other things like apache.... htop is clear all resoures is empty i also try on another vps but still have this problem

Comment: The pastebin.ubuntu only contains part of SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES. None of the other data is posted.  You may have better luck with using pastebin.com for getting your data posted so we can pick it up.  Each upload to pastebin.com has a 500KB limit. Post multiple files to avoid exceeding limit.

Comment: @WilsonHauck sorry i did it question edited

Comment: The posted SHOW GLOBAL STATUS; is missing the lines after slaves_running which would include UPTIME. Your 2 ulimit -a reports are fine. Please redo B) - AFTER 24 hours of UPTIME and C) and E) and post to pastebin.com.  Optional very helpful information, if available includes - htop OR top for most active apps, iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device and core/cpu count, for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.  Identify any server with SSD or NVME for data storage, please.

Comment: If you run MariaDB on container (Docker), as [link]https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/issues/124 it seems a problem related to docker Networking. Also interesting the comment about the character encoding and collations